# Create an Array of n1 "zeros" and n2 "ones" in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm new to scala and I have a simple question.

What is the best way to create an Array[int] of length n1+n2 such that it has n1 "zero" elements and n2 one elements.

Example:

n1 = 3, n2 = 2

Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can do

```
scala> Array.fill(3)(0) ++ Array.fill(2)(1) 
res2: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```